# Cloud Functions to Cloud FireStore running locally but not when deployed

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I try to write a document to one of the subcollections in firestore. The code when served locally writes to firestore but when I deploy it, it doesn't write anything.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var db = admin.firestore();

exports.update = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
        db.collection('emails').doc(request.query.trackingid).get()
        .then( doc => {
            if (!doc.exists) {
                console.log('No such document!');
              } else {
                var viewRef = db.collection('emails').doc(request.query.trackingid).collection('views');
                var view = {
                    when: (new Date()).toUTCString()
                };
                viewRef.add(view)
                .then(ref => {
                    console.log("Document added");
                    return;
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log("Document creation failed", err);
                });
              }
              return;
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('Tracking ID not found', err);
            return;
        });
        response.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Comment: Also the logs doesn't log anything interesting

Standard status codes 200 or 304, and warnings of billing account not configured.

Comment: check redirect property in firebase.json and node.js version in local

Comment: there's no redirect, and rewrites is empty

Comment: Yea, i mean rewrite. You have to set rewrite values to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending a response before the work can complete.  For HTTP type functions, you are obliged to [send a response only after all the work is complete](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).  Cloud Functions will forcible terminate the function after the response is sent.

Note that `get()` and all of the promises derived from it are asynchronous, meaning that they return immediately, with the callbacks only being called when the work is complete.  And you have no guarantee about when that will be.

What your code is doing now is kicking off a `get()`, then immediately following up with the next line of code, which sends the response before the work is complete.  When this response is sent, Cloud Functions terminates the function, and your async work may not complete.

You need to only send the response after you are sure everything is done.  This involves understanding the structure of your promises in your code.

You may want to [watch my video series on using promises in Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/) to better understand how this works.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. 

I feel stupid as i assumed since the function is already fired it should complete and  I send a response code immediately.

Comment: It's a common mistake.  That's why we have the docs and videos to point to.

Comment: but why does it work locally ?

The very same code if I use 'firebase serve' instead of 'firebase deploy' works.

Are you saying cloud functions deliberately shuts down after response is sent while local node.js doesn't ?

Comment: The emulator doesn't work 100% exactly like the real thing.  It's just not clamping down on resources and attempting to reuse the same process.